# SharePoint 2010 enterprise migration to SharePoint 2013 - Test-SPsite FailedErrorCount

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell

I'm in the process of migrating intranet site in SharePoint 2010 to a new SharePoint 2013 farm. I have followed the steps from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/uksharepoint/archive/2013/03/18/scripted-installation-of-sharepoint-2013-and-office-web-apps-server-from-the-field-part-2.aspx).

Problem appeared when I ran the PowerShell command **Test-SPSITE** and got Failed error count as the bellow picture shows:

[image]

So, How can I display those errors that I can understand what this is about and resolve it to move forward with upgrading my site collection to SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint 2013 includes a set of rules that you can run against a site collection to verify that it is working as expected. These rules are part of the site collection health checks. You can run the health checks from the Site Settings page or by using Windows PowerShell.

Their are 7 predefined rules  in health checks, So from your screen i am seeing the 4 rules's result but not 3 one. I would run the test-spsite with rule id paramter for remaining and this way it will tell you which is failing. here are the list of Rules and their IDs( bold are missing from your report)

1. Conflicting Content Types   `befe203b-a8c0-48c2-b5f0-27c10f9e1622`
2. Customized Files   `cd839b0d-9707-4950-8fac-f306cb920f6c`
3. Missing Galleries   `ee967197-ccbe-4c00-88e4-e6fab81145e1`
4. Missing Parent Content Types  `a9a6769f-7289-4b9f-ae7f-5db4b997d284`
5. **Missing Site Templates**   `5258ccf5-e7d6-4df7-b8ae-12fcc0513ebd`
6. **Unsupported Language Pack References**   `99c946f7-5751-417c-89d3-b9c8bb2d1f66`
7. **Unsupported MUI References**   `6da06aab-c539-4e0d-b111-b1da4408859a`

Your command will be like this:

```
Test-SPSite http://<site name</sites/testsite -Rule 5258ccf5-e7d6-4df7-b8ae-12fcc0513ebd
```

[Run site collection health checks in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219720.aspx)